# Javascript empty field is not properly validate

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Well, I've a html form which validate by javascript. In this form there a **editor textarea** box. When this box is empty javascript alert message showing "page content require". That's Ok.

But after filled up the content then it's again showing me "page content require". What's is wrong in my code ?

**Javascript:**

```
function doStart()
    {       
    var page_name =  document.page.page_name.value; 
    var page_loc = document.page.page_location.value;   

    <?php

    $page_limit =  mysql_query("SELECT menu_name FROM cms WHERE username = '$username' AND cms_location = 1 ");
    $num_page_limite = mysql_num_rows($page_limit);
    ?>
    var num = <?php echo $num_page_limite; ?>


    var page_content = document.page.editor_kama.value; 
    var uploadobj = document.getElementById('myuploader');


    if(page_name == null || page_name == "")
    {
        alert("page name require"); 
        document.page.page_name.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
    else if(page_name.length > 15 )
    {
        alert("page name is too long");
        document.page.page_name.focus() ;
        return false;
    }

    if(page_loc == null || page_loc == "")
    {
        alert("Select page location");  
        document.page.page_location.focus() ;       
        return false;
    }
    else if(num == 5 && page_loc == 1)
    {
        alert("You already creaed 5 pages for your top menu.");
        return false;
    }

    if(page_content == null|| page_content == "")       
    {
        alert("Page content require");  
        return false;
    }

    if (uploadobj.getqueuecount() > 0)
    {
        uploadobj.startupload();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please browse files for upload");
    }

}
</script>
```

**HTML form:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1"  name="page" onSubmit="return validate()">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" style="float:left; position:relative;">           
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">Page Content</td>
    <td>
    <textarea cols="80" id="editor_kama" name="editor_kama" rows="30" class="textarea"><?php if(isset($_POST['editor_kama'])) echo $_POST['editor_kama'];?></textarea>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       //<![CDATA[

       CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor_kama', {
           skin : 'kama'
       });

       //]]>
    </script>
    </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create page" class="submit" id="submitbutton" onclick="doStart();return false;"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>            
</form>
```

Comment: have you got a page where we cant test it ? Have you try do test the length of the value ?

Comment: @kevpoccs no i don't. what should i do ?

Comment: @kevpoccs if I insert long text then still it's showing me "page content require."

Comment: @Alex You should make a test page or a fiddle so we can examine the problem.

Comment: @Alex, work with page_content.length, I think your page_content is always at null, have you check it just after his init ?

Comment: @kevpoccs how do i check with init ?

Comment: just after page_content do a console.log(page_content) with and without text in your textarea

Comment: @kevpoccs I'm sorry that I'm new in javascript that's why i create a simple validation but failed.

Comment: can you do a page test ? this could be easiest for we ;)

Comment: @kevpoccs ok, i'm doing it now.

Comment: @kevpoccs plz check it http://page1.belgic.eu/page.php

Comment: editor_kama hide the textarea named you think received, your page_content is always empty, so i think you have a method in the kama  editor to get the value of them, I've found the solution

Comment: @kevpoccs actually i'm trying to if the field is empty or not. If empty it's showing me error message if not then it's proceed..But i don't want the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is

```
var page_content = document.page.editor_kama.value;
```

by

```
var page_content = CKEDITOR.instances['editor_kama'].getData();
```

your editor generate a lot of code, you must use the documentation to interract with them.

**edit :**

replace `page_content == null|| page_content == ""` by `page_content.length ==  0`